# Is there a Digital Video Access Protocol just like DAAP let us to explorer/watch videos stored on PC form a mobile device?

Tags: video-streaming, daap

I have done a lot of search on Google intend to find the anwser,but unlunkily with no results. I want to watch some videos stored on my PC from my android phone. I have been using DAAP to listen my music. Is there a similar DVAP (Digital Video Access Protocol)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While DAAP can actually handle video as well as audio, in your situation it would be best to look for a UPnP server for the PC, and a UPnP client for Android. There is a lengthy list of both on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_UPnP_AV_media_servers_and_clients).